# Finding the value of all H2s on a page with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to find a solution on Google so I thought I would post it to the community. I need to use JavaScript to locate all the H2s on a page, get the innerHTML values and then loop them horizontally in a div (easy enough) to show a subheading anchor list at the top of the page. Can someone tell me or give me a hint on how I can use a JavaScript routine to locate all the H2s on a page? Thanks!

Comment: Using jQuery you could just do `$('h2').each({/* function */});` ?

Comment: Ah, excellent. I was just offering a jQuery solution in case you was using it. Seems you are! I've added this as an answer now :o)

Comment: `$('h2').each(function() {
     $('.nav').append($('', {text: $(this).text()});
});`

How far am I? I have a div on the page with a call of nav

Comment: You should just be able to use `$('.nav').append($(this).text())`. See this [here](http://jsfiddle.net/AF2GT/1)

Comment: Hmmm...doesnt seem to be working. I have this `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
 $('h2').each(function() {
  $('.nav').append($(this).text())
 });
</script>


</head>

<body>

<div class="nav">Nav: </div>


<h2>Hello</h2>
<h2>Goodbye</h2>
<h2>Aloha</h2>`

Comment: I've moved this to [a chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31680/discussion-between-joshua-m-and-wally-kolcz)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using jQuery, you could run something like this

```
$('h2').each({
    /* function */
});
```

Then to append to the `.nav` container you can run

```
$('h2').each(function() { 
    $('.nav').append($(this).text())
});
```

Comment: He doesn't even have to be using Jquery, he could just start using it for this part :)

Comment: Some people would argue you don't need the bloat of jQuery to do something that can be achieved with pure JS, however ;)

Comment: Yep, thats true! In this case Jquery would make things easier, although usually I would recommend JS.

Comment: Hey, I agree. jQuery makes it much easier in a lot of circumstances because I don't need to write the JS :o)

Answer (score 1):

Use [document.getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByTagName) to select all the `h2`s:

```
var h2s = document.getElementsByTagName('h2');
for(var i = 0, length = h2s.length; i < length; i++){
    // Do something with
    h2s[i].innerHTML;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, create an empty collection for the links you're going to create:

```
var $links = $();
```

Then, loop through each `h2` using [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/), providing `index` and `h2` as arguments — the first keep count, the second to get a reference of the current `<h2>` we're dealing with.

```
$('h2').each(function(index, h2){
    // If there is no id (to link to), create one based on the index 
    if(!h2.id){
        h2.id = 'header' + index;
    }

    // Get a jQuery object of the header
    var $h2   = $(h2);
    // Link will be an <a> with the same text as the heading, and will link to its id
    var $link = $('<a>').text($h2.text()).attr('src', '#' + h2.id);
    // Add this link to the collection
    $links = $links.add($link);
});
```

So now `$links` contains your table of contents. Assuming you want to chuck these links in after the `<h1>`, you'd do the following:

```
$links.insertAfter('h1');
```

…but of course you can do whatever you want with them at this point.